# Override router match to provide params definition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typechecking

I have a function in my component which will access the router parameters.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import type { Match } from 'react-router-dom';

@withRouter
export default class UserDetails extends Component {
  getUserContributions() {
    const { match: { params: { userId } } } = this.props;
    this.props.getUserContributions(userId);
  }
  // ... other non-relevant stuff.
}
```

However, flow will complain that `userId` is possibly undefined. This is predictable, given that this is how params is defined by `react-router-dom` by `flow-typed`. It would have no idea that there is a specific required key called `userId` that is of type `string`.

```
declare export type Match = {
  params: { [key: string]: ?string },
  isExact: boolean,
  path: string,
  url: string
};
```

I wanted to provide the definition for the route params as a type. Here is my first attempt:

```
type RouteParams = {
  userId: string,
}

type RouteMatch = Match & {
  params: RouteParams,
}
```

However, flow throws an error for this.

> property `params`. Property cannot be accessed on any member of intersection type

It appears this is because it is already defined on `Match`.

Is there any way to override a key at the specific definition space?